# What Should I Roll to See if a Character Remembers a Face?

Tags: dnd-4e, knowledge-check

### Motivation

I'm planning an adventure where a character runs into someone he's seen once. Because of the nature of the encounter, the NPC will remember the PC, but the PC might not remember the NPC.

Think like an important executive comes through your workplace, but you're just one of the random people in a cube.

It's not important to my story that the PC remember, and it's something he could fail at, so I was thinking I would roll for it. The outcome will simply determine whether I tell the player where his character saw the guy before. This would explain something that he'll probably be wondering about, but won't be able to investigate for some time.

### Question

If you want to roll to see if a player character recognizes an NPC, what would you roll against?

I was thinking maybe Insight like seeing through a disguise, but Perception would make more sense for recognizing a face, or maybe Intelligence or Wisdom to represent memory.

What should it be, why, and why shouldn't it be the other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As a DM, I typically ask for Wisdom checks in these situations.** My reasoning is as follows:

**Insight**: Used to determine the intentions, motives, and secrets of others - i.e., what, if anything, are they hiding? In this case, the NPC is neither attempting to hide nor attempting to convey anything, so Insight is not appropriate.

**Perception**: Used to notice things. From the Compendium: "The Perception skill encompasses perceiving things, most often by sight or sound." This would be my second choice, as you typically recognize someone by "perceiving" or "noticing" familiar things about them, but as described in the Compendium, this specific skill is more about awareness of the environment - tracks, traps, secret doors, etc - than interpersonal recognition.

**Intelligence**: As commonly used in D&D, Int refers to the ability to be logical and knowledgeable about a topic. The common explanation I've seen is that Int is "book smarts", while Wisdom is "street smarts". Recognizing people doesn't come from one's ability to remember facts in a book, or to draw logical conclusions from those facts. Therefore, Int is not suitable for representing social memory.

**Charisma**: While Cha is the basis for most social skills in D&D, facial recognition is not actually required to be socially adept (although it helps). Therefore, a straight Charisma check is not a good representation of facial recognition skill.

**Wisdom**: Again, as commonly used in D&D, Wis refers to the ability to comprehend things, to see how things fit together as part of a bigger whole. This includes pattern recognition, which is how most people recognize faces. You'll note that of the four options you suggested, three of them are Wisdom-based; this reflects the attribute's use in perceiving and comprehending the world around oneself. However, given the specific nature of both the Insight and Perception skills, a straight Wisdom check is more appropriate for as basic and general a task as recognizing someone.

Answer (score 3):

Turn it around. Given that this character's remembering doesn't matter one way or another, allow the player to turn it into a character defining moment (if a minor one.) Give the player the information about the NPC, then *ask* if the character remembers, and *why or why not*. You'll get a better reward from that character development than withholding the information.

Traditionally, a wisdom check against an [easy DC](https://web.archive.org/web/20151105054312/http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/drdd/2010September) would be the way to handle this if the player was uncertain.

Comment: I'm sure that would work quite well in some play groups, but I think my guys would rather I roll. I'll mention this possibility before I do though, thanks.